# Can magit show if a branch is ahead or behind?

Tags: magit

Git hosting web services like Bitbucket Server and GitHub provide a branch view that shows whether branches are ahead or behind master:

[image: github branches]

This is great for finding remote branches which have been merged and can be deleted.

Can I see whether remote branches are behind or ahead with magit?

I found [issue 1550](https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/1550) but that just shows the age and author, not the number of commits. `L L` gives:

[image: magit branches]

Comment: It does show it for me in the `refs` buffer, even though I don't have any specific settings for this. Maybe I'm using an older version than the one you have? In my version the tracked branch appears inside brackets and whenever there's a difference in commits between remote and local it shows the numbers.

Comment: Oh, but I think you would need to have local branch tracking `cons_function` for example, to see the difference between it and the remote, otherwise there's really nothing to show (Git doesn't know what to compare it to).

Answer (score 5):

I'm not aware of a place where this is available in a unified view.
As @wvxvw comments, the refs buffer will show ahead/behind counts
against the upstream branch but not an arbitrary branch.

The closest the refs buffer curently gets is showing the number of
commits each branch is ahead of a selected branch or revision.  By
default, things are compared to HEAD, but you can use <kbd>C-u y</kbd>
to select another branch.  Then, in the refs buffer, <kbd>C-y b</kbd>
will show the ahead counts for each branch.  If you press tab on a
line, it will expand to show the commits (with an indication of
whether each commit has been applied to the selected branch).

You could fairly easily produce the GitHub-like view by iterating over
the branches and calling 
`(magit-rev-diff-count "master" <branch>)`.